# WCF Authentication using basicHttpBinding and custom UserNamePasswordValidator

Tags: wcf

My first question is, is it even possible to use a custom UserNamePasswordValidor with basicHttpBinding?

I have a asp.net web site using Forms authentication and a custom membership provider. I realise that I could use the built in System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService to authenticate my client (a WPF app) but I don't want two service calls (one for auth service, one for logic).

So it seems that a custom UserNamePasswordValidator would be perfect for the job. In my client I can then have:

```
        var service = new MyServiceClient();
        service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
        service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";

        MessageBox.Show(service.SayHello());
```

I've seen this working with wsHttpBinding but ideally would like to test without an SSL certificate.

Alternatively, is it possible to make use of the AuthenticationService from within another WCF service?

To clarify what I mean above regarding authentication service, I don't want to have 2 service calls i.e:

```
            if (authService.Login("username", "password"))
            // then call my service
```

I know this a minor thing but the external developer of the client app is expecting just one service that takes the credentials and returns the required data.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: I'm in a similar situation. I need use a UserNamePasswordValidator with basicHttpBinding, without SSL (HTTPS) and without requiring a certificate installed on the server. In other words, I need the most simple and unsecured authentication method.

Comment: I do not believe it is possible to use a UserNamePasswordValidator with basicHttpBinding - at least from what I have read. In the end we opted for passing the username and password as parameters for each method call and validating the credentials. This works without SSL of course but I would not recommend it and your credentials would be sent in clear text.

Comment: Actually you can use UserNamePasswordValidator with basicHttpBinding. However it does require you use either <security mode="Message" (whcih requires a certificate) or mode="TransportWithMessageCredential". In other words you cannot send it clear text.

Comment: It's likely that the WCF team decided that sending cleartext passwords was such an incredibly bad idea that they didn't even want to give developers the ability to shoot themselves in the foot, hence why SSL is required.

Answer (score 4):

check ClearUserName binding: http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2008/11/introducing-wcf-clearusernamebinding.html It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I use UserNamePasswordValidator over basicHttpBinding on a couple of my current projects.  It works great; however, like Brett Robi mentioned in the comments, you need to have your Security mode set to Message or TransportWithMessageCredentials in order for the validator to be called.  These security modes require SSL through.

So in short - Yes you can over basicHttpBinding; however, only with SSL.  Removing the security mode and SSL removes the credential validations from being called.

Comment: You should be able to use a custom non SSL cert if this is a private service. You can then embed the cert into your app. There are other ways go go about it from what I'm ware that don't require SSL by using the message security option.